# Application fails to start after I upgrade MariaDB version from 10.6 to 10.10

Tags: java, sql, mariadb

I updated the MariaDB version from 10.6 to 10.10.3 and now my application fails to start with the following error:

> Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
> java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection
> has timed out.

The context.xml file that I'm using is:

```
<Context sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash="false">
    <Resource name="jdbc/app" auth="Container"
              type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" driverClass="net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy"
              jdbcUrl="jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://localhost/app?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"
              user="user" password="password" factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
              acquireIncrement="3" minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="200"
              idleConnectionTestPeriod="100" maxStatements="0" checkoutTimeout="30000"
              unreturnedConnectionTimeout="0" debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="false"/>

    <Resource name="jdbc/jackrabbit" auth="Container"
              type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/app_jack?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"
              user="user" password="password" factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
              acquireIncrement="2" minPoolSize="1" maxPoolSize="3"
              idleConnectionTestPeriod="100" maxStatements="0" checkoutTimeout="30000"
              unreturnedConnectionTimeout="0" debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="false"/>

</Context>
```

Complete application stacktrace:

```
2023-02-21 09:12:35,296 ERROR [or.sp.we.co.ContextLoader][main][user:] - <Context initialization failed>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'migrations' defined in class path resource [org/gs4tr/app/migration/spring/applicationContext-migration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292) [spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) [spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:966) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682) [catalina.jar:9.0.10]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.10]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:83) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:431) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.gs4tr.app.migration.Migrations.updateCurrentVersion(Migrations.java:93) ~[gs4tr-app-migration-7.10.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.gs4tr.foundation.modules.migration.AbstractMigrations.executeMigration(AbstractMigrations.java:103) ~[gs4tr-foundation-modules-migration-5.53.0.jar:?]
    at org.gs4tr.app.migration.Migrations.afterPropertiesSet(Migrations.java:36) ~[gs4tr-app-migration-7.10.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.19.jar:0.2.19]
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.19.jar:0.2.19]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:431) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.gs4tr.app.migration.Migrations.updateCurrentVersion(Migrations.java:93) ~[gs4tr-app-migration-7.10.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.gs4tr.foundation.modules.migration.AbstractMigrations.executeMigration(AbstractMigrations.java:103) ~[gs4tr-foundation-modules-migration-5.53.0.jar:?]
    at org.gs4tr.app.migration.Migrations.afterPropertiesSet(Migrations.java:36) ~[gs4tr-app-migration-7.10.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@45590059 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1505) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:431) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.gs4tr.app.migration.Migrations.updateCurrentVersion(Migrations.java:93) ~[gs4tr-app-migration-7.10.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.gs4tr.foundation.modules.migration.AbstractMigrations.executeMigration(AbstractMigrations.java:103) ~[gs4tr-foundation-modules-migration-5.53.0.jar:?]
    at org.gs4tr.app.migration.Migrations.afterPropertiesSet(Migrations.java:36) ~[gs4tr-app-migration-7.10.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 53 more
```

Does anyone know what is making the problem?

Tnx in advance!

Comment: Is MariaDB started? What are its logs?

Comment: @danblack [Warning] Aborted connection 1154 to db: 'app' user: 'user' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Comment: Can you show the full application stack trace?

Comment: @danblack stack trace posted on the question description.

Comment: is the new DB still listening on the default mariadb/mysql port: 3306?

Comment: @JohnWilliams Yes

Comment: Is using [MariaDB Connector J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-j/) that is more tested against the server an option?